# Spacemacs Deletes Packages After Installation. How do i midigate this

Tags: emacs

I am using spacemacs and I am attempting to install packages with M-x "package install $package-name". The particular package I am trying to install is SLY, A newer implementation of The SLIME REPL for Common Lisp. When I Install the package when I start up spacemacs it works fine. However when exiting spacemacs it somehow gets deleted. After googling this issue I found this page https://develop.spacemacs.org/doc/FAQ.html. I followed the instructions and changed my .spacemacs config. I added the line    `dotspacemacs-install-packages 'used-but-keep-unused`. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your personal packages to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`